# Angularjs: Change the status to a different status if 30 days have passed in current state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, frontend, momentjs, backend

Good Day,

I have a question regarding some logic,

My current task is to basically, change the status of a ticket if it reaches  30 days old on last updated date, then it changes its status, so I was curious how I can do this using moment.js and Javascript.

Hope the screenshot and explanation helps.

Please find code snip below.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - can you please include code showing what you have tried so far?

Comment: Please add a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: please add your code..

Comment: Hi I have added above the new methods I tried :)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, not a complete answer (and before code was added to the question) and not a good fit for a comment.

moments has a `.diff()` method:

```
var daysUntilTicketExpires = 30
var a = moment([2007, 0, 29])
var b = moment([2007, 0, 28])
var c = a.diff(b, 'days') // 1

if( c > daysUntilTicketExpires) {
    alert("uh oh")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi Keep this code somewhere in your code and
call moment.addRealMonth(autoCloseDate) function

This will help

`moment.addRealMonth = function addRealMonth(d) {
  var fm = moment(d).add(1, 'M');
  var fmEnd = moment(fm).endOf('month');
  return d.date() != fm.date() && fm.isSame(fmEnd.format('YYYY-MM-DD')) ? fm.add(1, 'd') : fm;

}
var nextMonth = moment.addRealMonth(autoCloseDate);`